# Equations to calculate a & b coefficients for DSP Bandpass filtering in Java

Tags: java, signal-processing

Actually I'm new in this DSP Field and this question answering community.
Currently I'm writing Java program to detect pitch (pitch detection) from a wav file using AMDF. I done this.
The problem is, I didnt use any filter to eliminate unwanted frequencies. So, I did some researches and end up here [Tarsos DSP - Bandpass IIRFilter](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/core/be/tarsos/dsp/filters/BandPass.java).
Actually I didnt have problem with the codes, I just confused the equations he used to calculate the coefficients. I already asked him for references (no reply yet), read the documentations, and read some books about IIR Digital Filter, but found no clue yet about the references.
Can anyone point me strong references for this code:

```
protected void calcCoeff()
  {
    float R = 1 - 3 * bw;
    float fracFreq = getFrequency() / getSampleRate();
    float T = 2 * (float) Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * fracFreq);
    float K = (1 - R * T + R * R) / (2 - T);
    a = new float[] { 1 - K, (K - R) * T, R * R - K };
    b = new float[] { R * T, -R * R };
  }
```